# Is there a unique identifier for a saved netword on an Android device?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, ssid, bssid

If I have to do some specific actions while connected to a specific wifi network, what can I save inside my DataBase to be sure that I'm connected exactly to that network?
I saw that Android doesn't save the BSSID of a saved network but only the SSID and multiple profile with the save SSID are allowed so I can't use it.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? What did you end up doing to identify a wifi network uniquely?

Comment: Did the answer below cover you ? if yes accept it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?  [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks%28%29) says it returns the BSSID of saved networks too.